# Theatertatsache

Tags: translation

What does this word, and this use of 'Tatsache' mean?

Example:

> Am Ende der Rutschbahn in den Abgrund wartet der feste Boden der
>   Theatertatsachen, markiert durch ein Dutzend Äxte.

[Source](https://m.faz.net/aktuell/2.1747/das-absurde-ist-da-graf-oederland-neu-inszeniert-16637255.html).

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. As you figured out already the determiner and the primary word, you might have also came upon the idea of starting a translation from end to start? For this word: first getting the idea behind `Tatsache(n)`, then trying to narrow it down with `Theater`. In current case it seems far from obvious, maybe later this "trick" is useful. The leftover problem stays untouched: get to know where to split a long word into useful parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a word play on the phrase:

> [Auf den Boden der Tatsachen zurückgeholt werden](https://www.dict.cc/?s=boden+der+tatsachen)

Ignoring the extra words, the sentence would read as

> Am Ende der Rutschbahn in den Abgrund wartet der Boden der Tatsachen, markiert durch ein Dutzend Äxte.

Thinking about it, it is an even more fantastic pun. I'm not sure if it was intended by the author, but I couldn't let it go (read this with a wink): A *Tatsache* is generally translated as *fact*. But you can get a different meaning if you split up the word into *Tat*, an act or a crime and *Sache* which is a *thing*. Reading it like this, the word becomes "crime thing", which an axe can be (thinking of murder weapon). 
Also, often the adjective "hart" is used (*harter Boden der Tatsachen*), to really emphasize you get knocked back to earth. In this case, *fest* works as well.

So all in all, the fantastic ride on the slide is percipitously interrupted by theatre props - namely axes.

Comment: Whoever voted (-1), would you care to explain so I can improve on this answer?

Comment: I agree with the first part, but I think you are reading to much into it. But who knows, as it's the feuilleton ^^.

Comment: Hm, I agree, it might not have been intentional (added this to the post), however I can't unsee it now :D

Comment: The downvote is mine out of two reasons. 1) There is no word play in the context. 2) The explanation of "Tatsache" is fully OT, aber so was von!

Comment: The second part should be read with a wink, but I'm pretty sure on the first part, as it is a common figure of speech.

Comment: Winks should be signalled! Never heard about meta-clues?

Comment: Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Is it about the etymology of "Tatsachen" hier? Simply ridicoulous to the same extent to which most answers are devoid of any expertise at all!

Comment: Is this what my rants read like? I hope not! I very much dig the allusion to *Tat* "crime", but this is chiefly not to be understood that way in *Tatsache*, even if *Sache* itself also seems to have an origin in archaic legalese. The reference to *fest* is not understandable at all. Wordplays live from brevity in most cases.

Comment: As I said, read it with a wink. If you say "harter Boden - " or "fester Boden der Tatsachen" doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: Hart and fest are either superfluous or underdeveloped here (maybe you should read *more* into it?). I'd also disagree that this is a 'fantastic' word play. But I guess you'd be able to reveal even more hidden treasures (or primitive Pennälerlyrik?) by actually referencing what OP missed/omitted to mention: 'Graf Öderland' and *this* specific "surrealistic" version of the play (Tunnel/pipe as stage…). Mostly agreed except for 'fantastic' if meant as 'great', agreed even on that if meant as ['not4'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fantastic)…